# how to capture a particular value in dropdow attribute magento

Tags: magento, attributes, label

I have an attribute called "Tam" type dropdown

with several different values

need to display a custom image in list.phtml when the selected value is equal to "Regulável"

can anyone help me how to capture this specific value and display the image?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery code, it is simple way
you can get its value by

```
 jQuery(this).value;
```

You also need to get image path by jQuery and you can replace image with jQuery.